# TabbedActivity: When click on a button take me to different tab

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabs

I have implemented 3 tabs using TabbedActivity. I have a button in tab1 when I click on it it should take me to the tab2 (just like what happens when I click on tab2). Can anyone help me out with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This class was deprecated in API level 13.

Answer (score 0):

use function :

```
getTabHost().setCurrentTab(int index);//getTabHost().setCurrentTab(1);
```

in your button click listener.